# How to set the equality comparison between two objects present in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, list

How can I set the equality comparison behavior between two objects whose class is defined by me that are stored in an object of type ArrayList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this there exists in the Java language two fundamental methods called equals (...) and hashCode () that are declared in class java.lang.Object by default and are part of the core library of Java.

**You should implement these two methods in your classes that need to be compared!**

The `equals()` method is used to compare if one object is equal to the other.

The `hashCode()` method is used to generate an ID number corresponding to the object.

See more in:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html